# How to permanently delete a post meta entry?

Tags: posts, post-meta

[delete_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta) seems to merely clear out the value for a given post meta key. It doesn't really completely delete the row. I've been digging a lot, but I can't seem to find any function out there that deletes the post meta entry completely.

Please, could anyone point me in the right direction? Do I have to use `$wpdb` to delete the row fully or is there a tucked away function to do this for me?

**Edit:**

The following has been tested and it's working, but it's using `$wpdb`. Is this the proper way to do it?

```
$wpdb->delete( $wpdb->postmeta, array( 'post_id' => 744, 'meta_key' => 'referrers' ), array( '%d', '%s' ) );
```

**Edit2:**

Here's my old code:

```
// $post_id contains an integer value
// $referrers contains an array
$referrers = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'referrers', true );
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $referrers ); $i++ ) {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "referrers_{$i}_contact_id" );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "_referrers_{$i}_contact_id" );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "referrers_{$i}_rule" );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "_referrers_{$i}_rule" );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "referrers_{$i}_amount" );
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "_referrers_{$i}_amount" );
}
```

The above works, but it merely clears out the values. Am I using is incorrectly? Have I missed something by accident?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`delete_post_meta will`** delete the meta row. `delete_post_meta` also uses **`wpdb`** class to delete the meta rows. Can you show us the full code.

For your information `delete_post_meta` executes the following mysql command

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id IN( "85" );
```

through `delete_metadata` function. meta_id 85 is just given for example purpose. It is dynamic. so you don't need to run your own mysql queries in order to avoid bugs and security risks.

NOTE: I don't have enough reputation to comment, so giving this message as answer.

Comment: Thank you WPTC! I've appended my other code above for you to have a look. God I hope it isn't some stupidly small thing :(

Comment: Never mind, it was a stupid mistake of mine. I swear, starring at stackexchange/overflow for like 5min lets you find mistakes instantly... that and right after posting a question you end up finding a solution. */shrug* such is life.

Comment: Do you wanted to delete `referrers` or `referrers_*contact_id` etc. Bcoz in the query you were deleting `referrers` and in the function you are not deleting `referrers`

Comment: @adamj cool you found out the mistake. May I know what mistake you did?

Comment: It was ridiculously stupid, but sadly it wasn't something that popped up immediately as it was done via AJAX. It didn't send across the `$post_id` to the above deletion code.